# How to create an xmlSchema in code with a single complexType element?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, serialization, xsd

I need to wrap an XML in a element tag before I pass it to a backend system.

The original, unwrapped XML element validates against its XSD files.
The wrapped one does not, of course.

How can I create an `XmlSchema` in code and give that to my `XmlSchemaSet` before I validate the XML?

This is the unwrapped xml which validates:

```
<ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="example.com/Service.xsd" 
             xmlns:ns1="example.com/Data.xsd" 
             xmlns:ns2="example.com/RequestSchema.xsd">
    <ns0:Info>
        <ns2:Id>12345</ns2:BpId>
        <ns2:Name>FOO</ns2:BpName>
        <ns2:Init>BAR</ns2:Initiator>
    </ns0:Info>
    <ns1:DATA>          
    </ns1:DATA>
</ns0:Request>
```

and this is the wrapped xml for which I want to add an XmlSchema in Code

```
<group xmlns:ns0="example.com/Service.xsd" 
       xmlns:ns1="example.com/Data.xsd" 
       xmlns:ns2="example.com/RequestSchema.xsd">
    <ns0:Request>
        <ns0:Info>
            <ns2:Id>12345</ns2:BpId>
            <ns2:Name>FOO</ns2:BpName>
            <ns2:Init>BAR</ns2:Initiator>
        </ns0:Info>
        <ns1:DATA>          
        </ns1:DATA>
    </ns0:Request>
<group>
```

This is what i have tried yet, which did not work:

```
var groupImport = new XmlSchemaImport { Namespace = "example.com/Service.xsd" };
var groupComplexType = new XmlSchemaComplexType
{
    Particle = new XmlSchemaSequence(),
};
var groupElement = new XmlSchemaElement
{
    Name = "group",
    SchemaType = groupComplexType
};

var xmlSchema = new XmlSchema { TargetNamespace = "example.com/group.xsd" };
xmlSchema.Namespaces.Add("xs", "example.com/2001/XMLSchema");
xmlSchema.Includes.Add(groupImport);
xmlSchema.Items.Add(groupElement);
var xmlSchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
xmlSchemaSet.Add(xmlSchema);
xmlSchemaSet.Add(null, "Service.xsd");
xmlSchemaSet.Add(null, "Data.xsd");
xmlSchemaSet.Add(null, "RequestSchema.xsd");
```

I get this error when validating:

> Could not find schema information for the element 'group'.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons this might happen:

1. the schema location may be incorrect and the file where the `group` element is declared is not located;
2. the declarations were generated incorrectly,
3. in the wrong namespace,
4. in the wrong context, and so on.

Assuming that your other files are validating correctly, as you said in your question, this is the XSD you need to generate (assuming `Service.xsd` is located in the same directory):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:ns0="example.com/Service.xsd" 
            targetNamespace="example.com/group.xsd">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="Service.xsd" namespace="example.com/Service.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="group">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns0:Request" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here are some changes you can make in your file that will help you generate a valid schema.

1) **Missing import schemaLocation** In your code, you are generating this:

```
<xs:import namespace="example.com/Service.xsd"/>
```

The namespace is just a string, not a location. You should provide the URL of your schema using `SchemaLocation`. This will be used to generate the `<xsd:import>` correctly (this *might* not be necessary *if* your application finds your schema for you based on a local catalog). To generate this line:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="Service.xsd" namespace="example.com/Service.xsd" />
```

you should use:

```
var groupImport = new XmlSchemaImport { 
    Namespace = "example.com/Service.xsd",
    SchemaLocation = "Service.xsd"
};
```

2) **Empty sequence**: You are generating a new Schema which imports all your other schemas, creating a new complex type containing a sequence, but you are adding nothing to the sequence. This is what you are generating:

```
<xs:element name="group">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The result will be a valid declaration for a `group` element, but it won't allow you to place anything inside it. Based on your example, a `group` element should contain a `Request` element of the `example.com/Service.xsd` namespace. You need to generate:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="ns0:Request" />
</xs:sequence>
```

For that you will need to have access to the `sequence` object, and rewrite your code like this:

```
XmlSchemaSequence sequence = new XmlSchemaSequence();
var groupComplexType = new XmlSchemaComplexType
{
    Particle = sequence,
};
```

Then create an *element reference* declaration with a *qualified* name and add it to the sequence.

```
XmlSchemaElement requestRef = new XmlSchemaElement();
requestRef.RefName = new XmlQualifiedName("ns0:Request");
sequence.Items.Add(requestRef);
```

You will also have to add that prefix and namespace declaration to your schema so it will be able to validate your qualified types:

```
xmlSchema.Namespaces.Add("ns0", "example.com/Service.xsd");
```

It's probably a typo in your question, but the `xs` namespace should start with "http://www.w3.org" not "example.com":

```
xmlSchema.Namespaces.Add("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

With these changes, you should be able to generate a schema which will validate your file.

Here is your code modified with these suggestions:

```
var groupImport = new XmlSchemaImport { 
    Namespace = "example.com/Service.xsd",
    SchemaLocation = "Service.xsd"
};

XmlSchemaSequence sequence = new XmlSchemaSequence();
var groupComplexType = new XmlSchemaComplexType
{
    Particle = sequence,
};

var groupElement = new XmlSchemaElement
{
    Name = "group",
    SchemaType = groupComplexType
};

XmlSchemaElement requestRef = new XmlSchemaElement();
requestRef.RefName = new XmlQualifiedName("ns0:Request");
sequence.Items.Add(requestRef);

var xmlSchema = new XmlSchema { TargetNamespace = "example.com/group.xsd" };
xmlSchema.Namespaces.Add("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xmlSchema.Namespaces.Add("ns0", "example.com/Service.xsd");
xmlSchema.Includes.Add(groupImport);
xmlSchema.Items.Add(groupElement);

var xmlSchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
xmlSchemaSet.Add(xmlSchema);
xmlSchemaSet.Add(null, "Service.xsd");
xmlSchemaSet.Add(null, "Data.xsd");
xmlSchemaSet.Add(null, "RequestSchema.xsd");
```